# Any method to determine class of an instances?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Decision trees one usually has to determine for each observation (instance) the outcome-class (e.g. sunshine, rain, ...).

I'm wondering if there is any data mining algorithm out there that can group instances based on an attribute that determines the class.

Here is an Example:

```
day, outlook, temp, humidity, windy, play
1, sunny, 85, 85, false, no
2, sunny, 80, 90, true, no
3, overcast, 80, 90, true, no
3, rainy, 80, 90, true, no
```

In this case I could for instance use play or outlook as an outcome-class.

My question is if there is any algorithm or method out there that would tell be that for instance outlook is an attribute that I could use as an outcome-class.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question right. What you want to do is detect the attributes that would imply that an instance belong to a specific class?

This is a very simplified and naive example but I hope it can help, given the attributes: "wet floor", "people with umbrellas"; they are probably very related to the class "rain". 

Regards,

Comment: I rephrased my question and added an example.

Comment: you can try Weka, i think it has a tool to do feature ranking .. it will tell you the most discriminating features for all the instances .. is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I'm looking for. 

I'm looking for a (semi) automated method/algorithm where in the example above an algorithm could group all instances by their outlook. Basically, it tells me that the outlook is the best segmentation feature and instances {1,2} = sunny and {3, ...} = overcast ...

Comment: I think it is still not clear what you want to achieve. However, it does sound like feature weighting is what you are looking for, as @AhmedKotb suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, continuous attributes will not work.

But other than that, any discrete attribute could work.

The question is, what do you *want* to do, **how would a computer program know**?

You will have to tell it which is your output, and which are your inputs.

Some programs will of course apply heuristics, i.e. if an attribute is named "class" or uses a special "class" type, it will automatically be chosen as output, and the remainders as inputs.